# Magento 2 : Code Explanation for plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have override a template file `Magento_Payment::info/default.phtml` using following method this template is declared only in

```
/Magento2/vendor/magento/module-payment/Block/Info.php
```

file.

The below code works fine, but i want to know how it actually works as i did not find `toHtml` method in the above file.

Any thoughts ?

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Block\Info">
        <plugin name="module_paympent_view_override_template" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Payment\Block\Info" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Info.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Payment\Block;
 
class Info
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Payment\Block\Info $subject)
    {        
            $subject->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::info/default.phtml');        
    }
}
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

`toHtml` function defined in "**Magento/Framework/View/Element/Template.php**" file in which "**Magento/Payment/Block/Info.php**" file extends. Check below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can we use it on plugin beforeToHtml ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're "plugging in" to the toHtml method called inside the `\Magento\Payment\Block\Info`, this generates an interceptor class which intercepts all calls that can be intercepted and searches any associated plugins for methods defined with the `before`, `after`, or `around` pattern. So when the `\Magento\Payment\Block\Info` block calls `toHtml` (which is most definitely defined in its parent class `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`=> `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`) the interceptor will intercept it and call `beforeToHtml`.
For more information I would recommend reading this [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for how plugins work and their limitations

Comment: Thanks for the answer.